# Angular ng-resource POST sending query params not JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I'm trying to get my first ng-resource example working. The problem is it's sending the data as query params rather than JSON.

I have this service for my REST resource. REST_URL_PREFIX is just a constant.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('Test', ['$resource', 'REST_URL_PREFIX', function Test($resource, URL_PREFIX) {
     return $resource(URL_PREFIX + 'test/:id');
  }]);
```

Get's used like this.

```
var obj = {name: 'Test', num: 12345};
var objRest = new Test();
objRest.$save(obj);
```

I can see in the console that this calls the web service like this:

```
POST http://server/rest/test?name=Test&num=12345
```

What I'd like is for it to call like this:

```
POST http://server/rest/test
```

But with the JSON in the body of the request.

```
{name: 'Test', num: 12345}
```

The content type of the request is application/json automatically so I would've thought it would send JSON?

Have I missed something? I did spend quite some time searching and there are a number of similar questions but none solved my problem.

**Edit**
Ultimately I want this to submit details from a form.

```
$scope.submit = function(test) {
  > Code to save test parameter using Test resource required here
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.createTest = function () {
   var newTest = new Test;
   newTest.name = "new name";
   newTest.nume="123";

    newTest.$save();

};
```

Comment: @Sylvester: Please elaborate on your answer, explaining what the code does and how it solves the problem, to help others who see it.

Comment: @sylwester This works. I then tried it in my controller as $scope.newTest, this works too. As soon as I add inputs that use ng-model on newTest I get the error newTest.$save is not a function. Does that make sense or should I add code to the question?

Comment: I just tried that. Main difference with things I'd tried before is whether you use brackets with the new operator. E.G. new Test() or new Test. In either case I get the same error. test.$save() is not a function.
If I create a new Test within that function and copy the properties manually then it works. If I use angular.copy then it doesn't.

Comment: can you create jsbin or plunkr for your controller I can help you.

Comment: I just tried a plunkr but couldn't get it to give me the same error. It gives a different error about $injector. This was using your code from jsbin. Sorry. :(

Comment: I'm a fool! I tried your example and it worked. The crucial difference between your code and mine was that my $scope.newTest was called $scope.object. (The page is displaying AS400 objects) I renamed object to as400object and it works! Wouldn't have found it without your help and patience though. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

The original poster had the following code:

```
var obj = {name: 'Test', num: 12345};
var objRest = new Test();
objRest.$save(obj);
```

However what is not immediately obvious from the accepted answer and hence my post to try and clear this up. Is that the $save function is being used directly on the $resource service. In the context of this code the `new Test()` will create an instance of the angular resource class, which is used to make RESTful calls.

The function that should be being used is the `save` function not the `$save`.

The following code is what the @Ben Thurley should be using instead:

```
var obj = {name: 'Test', num: 12345};
var objRest = new Test();
objRest.save(obj);
```

The difference is VERY subtle but means that the POST call is made with query parameters instead of JSON in the http request body.

I suspect the only reason the `$save` method exists on the resource object is so that is can attach it to the objects it bring back during a get/query request. The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) only mentions `$save` in context of it being used on one of the objects returned from a request.

So for example:

```
var myRESTResourceEndPoint = $resource('/foo/:bar', {bar: null});
var foo = myRESTResourceEndPoint.get({bar: 123});
```

Then `$save` is valid in this context:

```
foo.$save();
```

Where as `save` is valid in this context:

```
myRESTResourceEndPoint.save();
```

The confusion occurs because the following code will yield a result but not in the way that was intended:

```
foo.$save(foo);
```

or

```
myRESTResourceEndPoint.$save(foo);
```